# Sort by two properties using different sort-directions with SortableMixin

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm retrieving posts using `findAll` (because it auto-updates when new posts are pushed to the store).

Therefore I'm doing the sorting in the controller using the `SortableMixin`.
You can specify multiple sort-properties but the sort-direction for both properties are different.
It would isPublished -> Ascending, createdAt -> Descending (Show drafts first, then the rest starting with the latest).

```
sortProperties: ['isPublished','createdAt'],
sortAscending: false
```

How can I make this work without sacrificing the auto-updating template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this article](http://balinterdi.com/2014/03/05/sorting-arrays-in-ember-dot-js-by-various-criteria.html), you can do something like:

```
items: [ /* blah blah */ ],
sortProperties: ['isPublished:asc', 'createdAt:desc'],
sortedItems: Ember.computed.sort('items', 'sortProperties')
```

Personally I always just write a custom `sortFunction` when using the `SortableMixin`, but this looks like a nifty shortcut.